# How to make rectangle draggable in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on the re-sizable and drag-able rectangles in HTML5
Here is my JSFiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cpvxf/128/)
In this code, I am able to draw re-sizable rectangle but not able to drag with mouse events.`

```
    //Make the DIV element draggagle:
    dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

    function dragElement(elmnt) {
      var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
      if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
        /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
        document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      } else {
        /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
        elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      }

      function dragMouseDown(e) {
        Move

e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
      }

      function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        // set the element's new position:
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
      }

      function closeDragElement() {
        /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
      }
    }
```

Comment: For that you need to create a clickable/draggable object in the middle of the rectangle. Same concept as the resize corners but keep it fixed at the center of the rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

To drag and drop shapes with Jquery UI, we can set the `draggable` property
to true when we instantiate a shape, or we can use the `draggable()` method.
The `draggable()` method enables drag and drop for both desktop and mobile
applications automatically.

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/a8tdh0qu/

```js
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        rect = {},
        drag = false,
        mouseX,
        mouseY,
        closeEnough = 10,
        dragTL = dragBL = dragTR = dragBR = false;

    function init() {
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);

        rect = {
            startX: 100,
            startY: 200,
            w: 300,
            h: 200
        }
    }

    function mouseDown(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        // if there isn't a rect yet
        if (rect.w === undefined) {
            rect.startX = mouseY;
            rect.startY = mouseX;
            dragBR = true;
        }

        // if there is, check which corner
        //   (if any) was clicked
        //
        // 4 cases:
        // 1. top left
        else if (checkCloseEnough(mouseX, rect.startX) && checkCloseEnough(mouseY, rect.startY)) {
            dragTL = true;
        }
        // 2. top right
        else if (checkCloseEnough(mouseX, rect.startX + rect.w) && checkCloseEnough(mouseY, rect.startY)) {
            dragTR = true;

        }
        // 3. bottom left
        else if (checkCloseEnough(mouseX, rect.startX) && checkCloseEnough(mouseY, rect.startY + rect.h)) {
            dragBL = true;

        }
        // 4. bottom right
        else if (checkCloseEnough(mouseX, rect.startX + rect.w) && checkCloseEnough(mouseY, rect.startY + rect.h)) {
            dragBR = true;

        }
        // (5.) none of them
        else {
            // handle not resizing
        }

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        draw();

    }

    function checkCloseEnough(p1, p2) {
        return Math.abs(p1 - p2) < closeEnough;
    }

    function mouseUp() {
        dragTL = dragTR = dragBL = dragBR = false;
    }

    function mouseMove(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        if (dragTL) {
            rect.w += rect.startX - mouseX;
            rect.h += rect.startY - mouseY;
            rect.startX = mouseX;
            rect.startY = mouseY;
        } else if (dragTR) {
            rect.w = Math.abs(rect.startX - mouseX);
            rect.h += rect.startY - mouseY;
            rect.startY = mouseY;
        } else if (dragBL) {
            rect.w += rect.startX - mouseX;
            rect.h = Math.abs(rect.startY - mouseY);
            rect.startX = mouseX;
        } else if (dragBR) {
            rect.w = Math.abs(rect.startX - mouseX);
            rect.h = Math.abs(rect.startY - mouseY);
        }
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        draw();
    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#222222";
        ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
        drawHandles();
    }
   
function drawCircle(x, y, radius) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
}

function drawHandles() {
    drawCircle(rect.startX, rect.startY, closeEnough);
    drawCircle(rect.startX + rect.w, rect.startY, closeEnough);
    drawCircle(rect.startX + rect.w, rect.startY + rect.h, closeEnough);
    drawCircle(rect.startX, rect.startY + rect.h, closeEnough);
}

    init();
    
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        rect = {},
        drag = false,
        mouseX,
        mouseY,
        closeEnough = 10,
        dragTL = dragBL = dragTR = dragBR = false;

    function init() {
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);

        rect = {
            startX: 100,
            startY: 200,
            w: 300,
            h: 200
        }
    }

    function mouseDown(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        // if there isn't a rect yet
        if (rect.w === undefined) {
            rect.startX = mouseY;
            rect.startY = mouseX;
            dragBR = true;
        }

        // if there is, check which corner
        //   (if any) was clicked
        //
        // 4 cases:
        // 1. top left
        else if (checkCloseEnough(mouseX, rect.startX) && checkCloseEnough(mouseY, rect.startY)) {
            dragTL = true;
        }
        // 2. top right
        else if (checkCloseEnough(mouseX, rect.startX + rect.w) && checkCloseEnough(mouseY, rect.startY)) {
            dragTR = true;

        }
        // 3. bottom left
        else if (checkCloseEnough(mouseX, rect.startX) && checkCloseEnough(mouseY, rect.startY + rect.h)) {
            dragBL = true;

        }
        // 4. bottom right
        else if (checkCloseEnough(mouseX, rect.startX + rect.w) && checkCloseEnough(mouseY, rect.startY + rect.h)) {
            dragBR = true;

        }
        // (5.) none of them
        else {
            // handle not resizing
        }

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        draw();

    }

    function checkCloseEnough(p1, p2) {
        return Math.abs(p1 - p2) < closeEnough;
    }

    function mouseUp() {
        dragTL = dragTR = dragBL = dragBR = false;
    }

    function mouseMove(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        if (dragTL) {
            rect.w += rect.startX - mouseX;
            rect.h += rect.startY - mouseY;
            rect.startX = mouseX;
            rect.startY = mouseY;
        } else if (dragTR) {
            rect.w = Math.abs(rect.startX - mouseX);
            rect.h += rect.startY - mouseY;
            rect.startY = mouseY;
        } else if (dragBL) {
            rect.w += rect.startX - mouseX;
            rect.h = Math.abs(rect.startY - mouseY);
            rect.startX = mouseX;
        } else if (dragBR) {
            rect.w = Math.abs(rect.startX - mouseX);
            rect.h = Math.abs(rect.startY - mouseY);
        }
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        draw();
    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#222222";
        ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
        drawHandles();
    }
   
function drawCircle(x, y, radius) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
}

function drawHandles() {
    drawCircle(rect.startX, rect.startY, closeEnough);
    drawCircle(rect.startX + rect.w, rect.startY, closeEnough);
    drawCircle(rect.startX + rect.w, rect.startY + rect.h, closeEnough);
    drawCircle(rect.startX, rect.startY + rect.h, closeEnough);
}



init();

$('#canvas').on('mousedown', function() {
    $("#canvas").draggable();
}).on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {

});
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #F0F0F0;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Firefog Drag</title>

</head>
<body>
<p>Drag the corners to resize</p>
<canvas id="canvas"  width=500 height=500></canvas>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I also want to know how to resize the same rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by using jquery.ui.css.

```
$("#canvas").draggable();
```

drag box by using mouse left click and resize box by using mouse right click

[click here to check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MAEvS/1842/)

for delete button

```
   <input type="button" value="Delete" id="btnDelete"/>
     $("#btnDelete").click(function () {
            $("#canvas").remove();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have one more query, I want to delete the particular rectangle using delete button among many.

Comment: do you want delete button separately or delete by using keyboard button

Comment: I want the delete button separately.